# Content goes below the button when the height is adjusted

Tags: html, css, less

I have spent several hours(8+) on this. I am new to Less and trying to adjust the height of this button in bootstrap.less.

[image]

For some reason the X is not staying inside the button.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="listen-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <button type="button" class="bootbox-close-button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" ><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <div class="modal-body">




.bootbox-close-button {
    color: red;
    background-color:white;
    float:right;
    margin-top:15px;
    margin-right:5px;
    position:relative;
    font-size:30px;
    z-index: 3;
    height:20px;
}
.bootbox-close-button>span{
  padding:0px;
}
.bootbox-close-button:hover {
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing your ".bootbox-close-button" class and use bootstraps ".close" class. Then start styling from there by overriding what bootstrap already has setup.

Comment: hmm. how do I call bootstraps? just <class="close"> ?

Comment: Correct <button type="button" class="close">

Comment: didn't recognize anything now

Comment: Here is a link to the doc and how the html should look. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals
Without being about to see more of the code. I feel like maybe the bootstrap.less is not actually getting added to the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is actually a combination of 3 properties, namely, `font-size`, `height` and `line-height` (though the last one is not explicitly set, ***that is the source*** of the problem). When the `line-height` is not set explicitly on any element, the default value, which is `normal` will be applied by User Agent and the below is what the [specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#line-height) say about how the `normal` is interpreted.

> A value of 'normal' sets the 'line-height' to a reasonable value for the element's font. It is suggested that UAs set the 'normal' value to be a number in the range of 1.0 to 1.2.
>
> When a numerical value is specified, the line height is given by the font size of the current element multiplied with the numerical value.

So, it is always very likely that the calculated `line-height` is more than (or atleast equal to the font's size). In this case, the calculated `line-height` seems to be somewhere around 34px (approximately a factor of 1.1 based on the font). Since the `line-height` is more than the `height` the text is pushed down below.

The below is [an extract from the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#the-height-of-lines) of how `line-height` influences formatting of a block element:

> The 'line-height' may be smaller than the height of the text, in which case the leading will be negative.

In the below snippet, I have added one more button and have given it a `line-height` smaller than the `height` of the button and you'd now see how it is within the button because the leading is negative.

```css
.bootbox-close-button {
  color: red;
  background-color: white;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 30px;
  z-index: 3;
  height: 20px;
}
.bootbox-close-button:nth-of-type(1) {
  line-height: 16px; /* add this */
}
.bootbox-close-button>span{
  padding: 0px;
}  
.bootbox-close-button:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="listen-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <button type="button" class="bootbox-close-button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="bootbox-close-button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> 
      </button>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Some content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The other options that you have to get the text within the button are (a) set a smaller `font-size` than the `height` * `factor` but that will make the cross look smaller (b) don't set any `height` to the button but that will make the button look larger.

Comment: Thanks Harry for explaining this. The line-height was exactly what the issue was. An easily missed element of the DOM because you don't see the font's edges anywhere in Chrome. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes @PeterGMac. These sort of things have stumped me a lot in the past too. A lot of times the "computed" values go under the radar because we think *I haven't set it, so it shouldn't affect me* but those are almost always what ends up affecting without we knowing.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it shows the button at the height you've set it to (20px). You might change that to a larger number and set floating on the `span` to make sure it joins the same content flow.

Comment: floating on span? so { float:right} ? how is that going to help adjust height?

Comment: because the parent element only expands if there's content inside it which has the same flow (floating in this case)